# different between Bandpass chanel and Baseband channel?

Tags: bandwidth

What is the different between Band-pass Chanel and Base-band channel?

can we convert analog data to analog signal using base-band signal?

Comment: This question is better suited for [electronics.se], where you can get an explanation for ADCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, passband is a frequency range between two (non-zero) frequencies. Baseband is a range starting at (close to) 0 Hz and some upper frequency.

> can we convert analog data to analog signal using base-band signal?

Baseband is a frequency band you can use for *transmitting* a signal, it doesn't convert anything. The signal is generally analog and can carry analog or (mostly) digital data.

To "convert" data to an analog signal and back you require a encoding and modulation scheme, like e.g. the Manchester code used for early Ethernet, or 64b/66b block code, PAM line encoding and scrambling used for more modern copper-based variants, all using baseband signaling (well, nearly).